# how to find a row with minimum changes

Tags: r

I have a data set like this

```
df <- structure(list(Idm = c("AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "AAAA", "AAAA", "AAAA", 
"AAAAA", "AAAAA", "AAAAA", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BBB", "BBB", "BBB", 
"BBBBB", "BBBBB", "BBBBB", "CCCC", "CCCC", "CCCC", "CCCCC", "CCCCC", 
"CCCCC"), name = c("G", "A", "B", "G", "A", "B", "G", "A", "B", 
"G", "A", "B", "G", "A", "B", "G", "A", "B", "G", "A", "B", "G", 
"A", "B"), value = c(2506.3, 5306.7, 6558.1, 2270.1, 5449.3, 
5790.2, 334.1, 947, 1128.2, 809, 1944, 2539, 1302.3, 3447, 4107.7, 
2562.7, 5127.6, 4585.8, 911, 5121.9, 6313.4, 832.8, 1230.2, 1180.8
), sd = c(1865.19913950227, 2221.04246770145, 5885.17898538354, 
1273.08845332915, 2008.35456364989, 3037.90616433973, 181.270083944741, 
446.8334626383, 490.805504587442, 633.895459309604, 961.277571776227, 
2444.30575487874, 1012.39068051815, 1393.79545127684, 5826.31668323421, 
1476.91924739755, 1508.60484223007, 4258.95203228838, 838.051710815031, 
2911.84582696268, 4510.54727758543, 507.433227134369, 562.122249455875, 
1674.86096835926), n = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), groups = structure(list(Idm = c("AAA", "AAAA", "AAAAA", 
"BB", "BBB", "BBBBB", "CCCC", "CCCCC"), .rows = structure(list(
    1:3, 4:6, 7:9, 10:12, 13:15, 16:18, 19:21, 22:24), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to know which one of these Idm has the Lowest variation for instance

```
AAAAA   G   334.1   181.2700839
AAAAA   A   947     446.8334626
AAAAA   B   1128.2  490.8055046
```

and this one are having the less variation across 3 repeat

```
CCCCC   G   832.8   507.4332271 1
CCCCC   A   1230.2  562.1222495 2
CCCCC   B   1180.8  1674.860968 3
```

I can see that by plot as follows

[image]

I am thinking of getting the average of each 3 replicate (value) and each three (sd) and the one with a lower of both value and sd is the one with the lowest variation

Comment: @IceCreamToucan at the end SD is the most important , if there are two groups that have the lowest but one has lower SD , that is preferred. I showed two groups with the lowest ones, but CCCC is really the lowest based on the figure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clarification is needed on the question, but if you just want the rows with the minimum standard deviation by group then you can use `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Idm) %>%
  slice(which.min(sd)) %>%
  arrange(sd)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 5
# Groups:   Idm [8]
  Idm   name  value    sd     n
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1 AAAAA G      334.  181.     1
2 CCCCC G      833.  507.     1
3 BB    G      809   634.     1
4 CCCC  G      911   838.     1
5 BBB   G     1302. 1012.     1
6 AAAA  G     2270. 1273.     1
7 BBBBB G     2563. 1477.     1
8 AAA   G     2506. 1865.     1
```

Or you can sort each group and retain all data:

```
df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Idm) %>%
  arrange(Idm, sd)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 24 × 5
# Groups:   Idm [8]
   Idm   name  value    sd     n
   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1 AAAAA G      334.  181.     1
 2 AAAAA A      947   447.     2
 3 AAAAA B     1128.  491.     3
 4 CCCCC G      833.  507.     1
 5 CCCCC A     1230.  562.     2
 6 BB    G      809   634.     1
 7 CCCC  G      911   838.     1
 8 BB    A     1944   961.     2
 9 BBB   G     1302. 1012.     1
10 AAAA  G     2270. 1273.     1
# … with 14 more rows
```

Comment: sounds very good, would it be possible to show only the one with minimum one or a ranking of all ? from lower to higher?

Comment: @Learner Updated the answer to include these options too.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, I meant across 3 replicate not each of them separately . for instance if you look at the data, it has AAA 3 times each of them is one replicate.

Comment: @Learner The first answer gives you only the minimum for each Idm group. If you want to simply sort for each group and retain all data, then you can do what I've provided above.

Comment: something makes me confused is the name, it shows all as G, so based on the first the group AAA is the lowest ? that cannot be true, look at the AAAAA

Comment: It was not sorted. It's sorted now.